# Java generics, type erasure and type of a generic member

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Java has type erasure and people say that one can't determine the type of a generic object at runtime without hacks. Consider the code below

```
    public class TestClass<T> {

    private T genericField;

    public TestClass(T genericField) {
        this.genericField = genericField;
    }

    public void printTypeInfo() {
        System.out.println("Hi I'm a " + genericField.getClass());
        System.out.println("Am I a string? " + (genericField instanceof String));
        System.out.println("Am I a long? " + (genericField instanceof Long));
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        TestClass<String> genericString = new TestClass<>("Hello");
        TestClass<Long> genericLong = new TestClass<>(111111L);
        genericString.printTypeInfo();
        System.out.println("------------------");
        genericLong.printTypeInfo();
    }
}
```

It gives me the following result:

```
Hi I'm a class java.lang.String
Am I a string? true
Am I a long? false
------------------
Hi I'm a class java.lang.Long
Am I a string? false
Am I a long? true
```

Seems like type information is readily available at runtime. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine the type of any given object in `genericField` at runtime, but you cannot determine the difference between a `TestClass<X>` and a `TestClass<Y>` at runtime without examining some members that you know happen to be constrained by the generic type. That is you cannot determine the type parameter of a `TestClass<...>` given an instance of a `TestClass` alone.

Your code displays the type of `genericField`'s value, *not* the parameterized type of the `TestClass` instance. Try printing `this.getClass()` and you'll see its identical in both cases.

What you are "missing" is this: You are (understandably) making an incorrect connection between the fact that `genericField` itself holds an object (with a type) and the fact that `TestClass` has a generic type parameter. You are confusing the ability to determine the type of `genericField`s value with the ability to determine the type parameter specified to a `TestClass`. That is, while you can deduce what the type parameter was based on *your* knowledge that `genericField` is `T`, this is not the same as directly being able to determine what `T` was, which is impossible.

Another way to look at the previous paragraph is to consider these points:

- If `TestClass` had no members of type `T` then there's no other way you could extract `T`. Your code only "determines" what `T` was based on your own personal knowledge that `genericField` was declared as holding that same type (and therefore the object in it must be of that type, and therefore you can conclude that the generic parameter was likely that same type or some supertype of it).
- If you did not use generics, and `genericField` was just an `Object`, you'd still be able to determine the type of the object in `genericField`. That is, its type is "independent" of the generic type, except when you use generics the compiler places a constraint on the type. It's still just an arbitrary object after compilation, regardless of whether or not you used generics (which are really just a convenience, as you could do all of this without generics and just use `Object` and lots of casts instead).

Consider also the possibility of a `TestClass<Base>`, where `genericField` was assigned a `Derived`. Your code would correctly show that `genericField` was a `Derived`, but you have no way of knowing that the type parameter was a `Base` vs. a `Derived`, because the information was erased.

---

Also, to ram the above points home even further:

```
TestClass<String> genericString = new TestClass<String>("Hello");
TestClass<?> kludge = genericString;
TestClass<Long> genericLongButNotReally = (TestClass<Long>)kludge;

genericLongButNotReally.printTypeInfo();
```

Outputs the info for a `String` (this is why those "unchecked conversion" warnings are given, to prevent strange things like this), not caring about the fact that `genericLongButNotReally` was specified with a `Long` type parameter. The kludge is necessary to circumvent the good protection that the compiler offers when you use generic types; but at runtime it does not care.

Answer (score 4):

```
TestClass<Number> genericNumber = new TestClass<>(42L);
genericNumber.printTypeInfo();
```

This will print `Hi I'm a Long`  instead of `Hi I'm a Number`. You can see that `genericField` is a `Long` but you can't see that `T` was instantiated as `Number`.

Here's an example of something you can't do because of type erasure.

```
TestClass<?> generic = new TestClass<String>("Hello");

if (generic instanceof TestClass<String>) {
    System.out.println("It holds a string!");
}
else if (generic instanceof TestClass<Long>) {
    System.out.println("It holds a long!");
}
```

Comment: Very clear; also worth noting that printing `this.getClass()` in `printTypeInfo()` would yield identical results for both test cases, which helps highlight the difference between the ability to determine the type of `genericField`'s value vs. the ability to determine the type parameter of a `TestClass` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to get the type of a variable and the type of an object are two different things.

Just because you can get the type of `genericField` doesn't mean that you can see that T was a number.